# Mostrar conteúdo de acordo com o Select

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Como faço para que quando o usuário selecionar a unidade, mostre a div do conteúdo de acordo com a unidade selecionada? Seria com jQuery?

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Selecione a unidade</label><br>
  <select class="form-control" id="list-lugar" name="unidade">
    <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">Selecione uma Unidade</option>
    <option name="PMA" value="200">PMA</option>
    <option name="BRB" value="200">BRB</option>
    <option name="MTO" value="100">MTO</option>
    <option name="CN" value="100">CN</option>
    <option name="SCS" value="100">SCS</option>
    <option name="TPL" value="100">TPL</option>
    <option name="SBC" value="100">SBC</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="PMA">
  <h1>Conteúdo 1</h1>
</div>

<div class="BRB">
  <h1>Conteúdo 2</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Aqui tem uma opção que usa o `ID` com o mesmo nome do value do `option`, assim facilita e poupa algumas linhas de código. Repare que que o valor do value é o mesmo do ID, assim vc consegue uma regra que quando vc selecionar o `value="X"` ele mostra a `div` que tenha o `id="X"`

**OBS:** Só fiz as duas primeira opções funcionando para vc fazer o resto ir vendo como funciona a dinâmica

```js
  $(function() {
        $('.form-control').change(function(){
            $('.blocos').hide();
            $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
        });
    });
```

```css
  .blocos {
    display: none;
  }
```

```html
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Selecione a unidade</label><br>
      <select class="form-control" id="list-lugar" name="unidade">
        <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">Selecione uma Unidade</option>
        <option name="PMA" value="PMA">PMA</option>
        <option name="BRB" value="BRB">BRB</option>
        <option name="MTO" value="MTO">MTO</option>
        <option name="CN" value="CN">CN</option>
        <option name="SCS" value="SCS">SCS</option>
        <option name="TPL" value="TPL">TPL</option>
        <option name="SBC" value="SBC">SBC</option>
      </select>
    </div>
      
      <div id="PMA" class="blocos">
        <h1>PMA aqui</h1>
      </div>
      
      <div id="BRB" class="blocos">
        <h1>BRB aqui</h1>
      </div>
```

[Fonte que usei de referência](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975521/show-hide-div-based-on-select-option-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

Pode usar jQuery para isso, mas insira as `div`s dentro de uma *div-mãe* para ter uma referência de como selecionar `div`s irmãs. No exemplo, incluí as `div`s numa *div-mãe* `<div id="unidades">`. Com isso, você pode pegar o valor do `name` da `option` selecionada que é o mesmo nome da classe da `div` que quer mostrar:

```js
$("#list-lugar").change(function(){ // evento change
   $("."+$(":selected", this).attr("name"), "#unidades") // busca a div com a classe dentro da div mãe
   .show()     // mostra a div com a classe vinda do name
   .siblings() // seleciona as divs irmãs
   .hide();    // esconde as divs irmãs
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Selecione a unidade</label><br>
  <select class="form-control" id="list-lugar" name="unidade">
    <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">Selecione uma Unidade</option>
    <option name="PMA" value="200">PMA</option>
    <option name="BRB" value="200">BRB</option>
    <option name="MTO" value="100">MTO</option>
    <option name="CN" value="100">CN</option>
    <option name="SCS" value="100">SCS</option>
    <option name="TPL" value="100">TPL</option>
    <option name="SBC" value="100">SBC</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="unidades">
   <div class="PMA">
     <h1>Conteúdo 1</h1>
   </div>
   
   <div class="BRB">
     <h1>Conteúdo 2</h1>
   </div>
</div>
```

### Em JavaScript puro

```js
document.querySelector("#list-lugar").onchange = function(){
   var n = this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute("name");
   var d = document.querySelectorAll("#unidades div");
   for(var x=0; x<d.length; x++){
      d[x].style.display = ~d[x].className.indexOf(n) ? "block" : "none";
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Selecione a unidade</label><br>
  <select class="form-control" id="list-lugar" name="unidade">
    <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">Selecione uma Unidade</option>
    <option name="PMA" value="200">PMA</option>
    <option name="BRB" value="200">BRB</option>
    <option name="MTO" value="100">MTO</option>
    <option name="CN" value="100">CN</option>
    <option name="SCS" value="100">SCS</option>
    <option name="TPL" value="100">TPL</option>
    <option name="SBC" value="100">SBC</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="unidades">
   <div class="PMA">
     <h1>Conteúdo 1</h1>
   </div>
   
   <div class="BRB">
     <h1>Conteúdo 2</h1>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Jovem isso `$("."+$(":selected", this).attr("name"), "#unidades").show().siblings().hide();` é a mesma coisa que vc escreveu, ou se eu colocar tudo em uma linha seria errado?

Comment: Na mesma linha não é errado não. Eu gosto de separar às vezes pq fica mais fácil de ler e alterar.

Comment: Gostei da metodologia []'s